# Document organizer with OCR and email ingress

Tags: open-source, offline, document-management

I found this open source project some months ago but for the life of me can't remember what it's called. It had a weird name which I believe started with *A*. I'll list some of the features. Anything that does something like what is described will be acceptable, of course.

Purpose: Document organizer

Non-functional:

- Open source
- Can host on own hardware

Functional:

- Document categorization
- OCR for scanned documents
- Email integration (treats emails as documents)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you mean **Amber**, "an open-source document search engine with automated crawling, OCR, tagging and instant full-text search".

https://ambar.cloud/

https://github.com/RD17/ambar/

It seems to fulfill all of your requirements, including E-mail processing.