# I would like to tag documents/notes and search tags with logical AND and OR

Tags: windows, document-management, tags

I would like to tag documents and search tags with logical AND and OR

e.g. search for all documents tagged "genesis" OR "exodus"

search for all documents tagged "computer articles" AND "routers"

search for all documents tagged "computer-articles" AND ("routers" or "switches")

What programs would allow me to do that?

Answer (score 0):

I would say you are looking for document mangement software. I found [this answer](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/52428/50) which suggests using [Amber](https://ambar.cloud/)

> An open-source document search engine with automated crawling, OCR, tagging and instant full-text search

They have a live demo hosted [here](https://app.ambar.cloud/?query=).

Amber is free, but only if you build it from source code. Otherwise, they offer a docker image for a one-time payment of $50. [[Pricing]](https://ambar.cloud/pricing/)

Comment: I am looking for a windows program hence tagged windows

Answer (score 0):

RecentX can do this: https://www.conceptworld.com/RecentX . After creating the tags, you can click Ctrl key and choose multiple tags.

Comment: but have you used it? is it any good? it doesn't look like many people use it? I have just run into an issue pretty quickly https://superuser.com/questions/1585148/in-recentx-do-tags-disappear-after-a-file-is-moved